# How to enable quota on CENTOS 6.9 virtuozzo VPS?

Tags: linux, centos, webserver, vps

I'm new on server administration. Recently I purchased a new VPS but when I add a new user/Cpanel, it always shows unlimited disk quota. I have tried many times to enable quota but failed every time. My server is CENTOS 6.9 virtuozzo

1. Login to server via ssh
2. Switch to root user sudo su -
3. Edit /etc/fstab: `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

It shows me following entries in file:

```
none    /dev/pts        devpts  rw,gid=5,mode=620     0 0
none    /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults              0 0
```

I've added a new entry:

```
/dev/mydevicename  /home     ext3    defaults,usrquota,grpquota  1 2
```

4. Save and exit to terminal
5. Now run `mount -o remount /home` command but it return 
   mount: /home not mounted already, or bad option

I tried a different mount point with name **hbhome** then it return:

> mount: mount point /hbhome does not exist

Also I tried default mount point **/** and run  `mount -o remount /` but it returns:

> Permission denied

At this point I am clueless to how to achieve it. I also googled many times for the same issue but I didn't find anything which can resolve the issue.
Can someone tell me how to resolve this?